# How to incorporate Hadoop File System with OpenCL/GPU Code

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, opencl, gpgpu, gpu

[With reference to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495698/how-to-use-hadoop-mapreuce-framework-for-an-opencl-application)

My doubt is how to configure HDFS with other languages. Not able to find proper tutorials to incorporate HDFS with opencl/cuda codes. I have written my own codes for Map and Reduce in opencl. Both Map and Reduce functions are GPU's kernel functions. Now I want to use HDFS on multiple nodes to implement my codes.

Anybody please tell me the tutorials to implement GPU/OpenCL codes under HADOOP framework. Thank you in advance.

NOTE: I don't want to use APARAPI/JavaCL.

Answer (score 1):

HDFS is a file system; you can use HDFS file system with any language.

HDFS data is distributed over multiple machines, it is highly available to process the data in GPU computing.

For more information reference [Hadoop Streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/streaming.html)